# Wrong constant value in C

Tags: c, constants

I am trying to use 256 as a constant in C with #define. That equals 255 + 1 (which is 0xff + 1). And since in `limits.h`, `UCHAR_MAX` is 255, 256 should be equivalent to `UCHAR_MAX` + 1. So I write:

```
#include <limits.h>
#define BASE_NUM ((int)UCHAR_MAX)+1
```

So, when I do `printf("%f",1000.0/(float)BASE_NUM);`, it prints 4.921569, which is wrong (it would only be correct if `BASE_NUM` was 203.187).

However, by writing `printf("%f",1000.0/((float)UCHAR_MAX+1));`, I get 3.906250 as the output, and it is indeed correct. Therefore, `BASE_NUM` must not be equal to 256, but astonishingly, `printf("%d",BASE_NUM);` prints 256, which is clearly a contradiction, as `BASE_NUM` must not actually be 256.

I guess it has something to do with an overflow when I do the sum at the definition of the constant, but I really can't see what the problem exactly is, given that I am casting `UCHAR_MAX` to an int before adding anything to it, so there should be no overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `#define` in another set of parenthesis:

```
#define BASE_NUM (((int)UCHAR_MAX)+1)
```

Explanation:

Whenever you're having trouble with macros, just copy-paste their definition tho wherever you're using them and then evaluate from there:

```
printf("%f", 1000.0 / (float) ((int)UCHAR_MAX) + 1);
```

---

- First, `UCHAR_MAX` is cast to an `int` and becomes `255`. (here the cast is unnecessary as the constant `255` is already treated as an `int` by the compiler).
- Then it is cast to a `float` and becomes `255.0`.
- Then, because division takes precedence over addition in C, `1000.0` is divided by `255.0`
- And finally `1` is converted to a float, becomes `1.0`, and gets added to the result of the division `(1000.0 / 255.0 + 1.0) == 4.92`.

Comment: On a side note flagging your question as a duplicate was a stupid decision by whoever did it.

Comment: Indeed, your explanation solved the problem, thanks a lot! I personally don't think this is a duplicate, either, as I tried searching before and didn't find anything like my question, but I guess there may be another related question.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it did indeed help you! Also, yeah, your question being a duplicate doesn't make sense. You had a problem and you weren't aware of the cause, whereas the author of the linked question was asking exactly about the need for parenthesis inside of macros.

Comment: Anyone is free to nominate the question for reopening if they feel the closure was inappropriate.  In general (at least as far as I'm concerned) (a) a "duplicate" question needn't match exactly as long as the answer is the one the questioner needs, and (b) marking a question as a duplicate is in no way a criticism of the questioner for not having found that prior question; it merely says "here's your answer", and keeps people from wasting time re-answering.

Comment: Also there are often questions that often have trivial superficial - and wrong answers and often a better way in the canonical duplicate.

Comment: everything relates to your issue is answer in the other question, so definitely it's a duplicate. You couldn't find it because you used the wrong keyword. But next time read [read through the whole macro section in your C book before asking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/995714)

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor left your printf like this:

```
printf("%f\n", 1000.0/(float) ((int)(0x7f * 2 + 1))+1);
```

which is interpreted as: (1000.0/UCHAR_MAX) + 1